# How is Sublime Text implemented?

Tags: python, pyqt, wxpython, sublimetext, pygtk

How is Sublime Text's GUI implemented, is it using `pygtk`, `pyqt`, `wxpython` or something else?

Answer (score 4):

It uses a custom UI toolkit.  For more information see: http://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=2822114.

Comment: While the link in your answer may address the question, it is much better to include the information from the link in your answer, as external sites can change, rearrange, or disappear completely. Answers on Stack Overflow (and all Stack Exchange sites) should be able to stand on their own, with any external links for reference only.

Comment: why the author objective c? why not qt?